# document.elementFromPoint speed is slow

Tags: javascript, performance, element, point

I'm using `document.elementFromPoint` in a project and it seems very slow. 100,000 iterations takes 7051 ms.  100,000 iterations of `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` only takes 32ms. Why is `document.elementFromPoint` more than 200 times slower?  Is there an alternative that is faster?

```
function elementFromPointSpeed() {
    start=performance.now();
  for(var i=0;i<100000;i++)
  el=document.elementFromPoint(100,100);
  //el=document.getElementsByTagName("*"); 
    end=performance.now()
    console.log(end-start)
}
elementFromPointSpeed();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Function of DOM *elementFromPoint*  2 points given to get the topmos need to loop around multiple point of a the same element inside of all DOM tags and finally find the elements around the points **`x,y`** who are the topmos between us.

More info here :https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#documentlayout-elementfrompoint

The `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` only loop on the tag html (`html - head - body -  div - ul - li - dt - span - input`...) 
much faster than *elementFromPoint*.
Regards

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works. Is there another way to do this that would be faster?

Comment: My question, there is any particular reason of using this function? may be the alternative depends on what you should want to got as result in your context. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

There's an easy answer to this, no. If there's a native API specifically made for getting an element at a point, it would be absurd if another API did that more efficiently. As then there would be no reason to not make it use the other API internally.

A browser simply needs to take a lot of things into account if it wants to know which element is at a point.

Whereas `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` needs to basically do almost no filtering logic and can just return references to all elements.

It shouldn't surprise that it's orders of magnitude faster.

Sure, in theory it's probably possible to reduce the difference and make finding an element at a point faster. But browsers are not optimized for it because it's not a frequent use case.